# How to increase tmux pane numbers display time `ctrl-b q`

Tags: tmux

How can I increase the display time of the pane numbers seen with `ctrl-b q`?

When having lots of panes, it is sometimes not enough time to key in the one I want to switch to.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set it in an existing session with `ctrl-b :set display-panes-time 2000` for 2 seconds for example. To persist it, put the command into your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g display-panes-time 2000
```

This is documented in the tmux manpage (`man tmux`) under OPTIONS:

```
 display-panes-time time
    Set the time in milliseconds for which the indicators shown by the display-panes command appear.
```

Alternatively you can make it display the pane IDs **until you select a pane**, as Mark Stosberg suggested in his comment:

```
bind -T prefix q display-panes -d 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried it and due to the error I received, I believe that there must be a `-g` after `set` right?

Comment: You're right. I forgot to include it in my answer.

Comment: You can add this to your `.tmux.conf` to make the numbers appear until you select a pane: `bind -T prefix q display-panes -d 0`